# NullPointerException at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, servlet-filters, omnifaces

I run a Java EE 7 application on WildFly 8.2. I use OmniFaces 1.8.1.
I see in log files `NullPointerExceptions` related to `FacesViewsForwardingFilter`:

```
2015-02-11 15:42:22,870 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-12) UT005023: Exception handling request to /login: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:122) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
        at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
```

```
2015-02-11 15:42:31,524 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-15) UT005023: Exception handling request to /search.xhtml: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:153) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
        at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
```

During server startup I'm seeing this:

```
2015-02-11 12:28:35,667 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /terms/index: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.setViewHandler(ApplicationImpl.java:583) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.setViewHandler(ApplicationWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingApplication.setViewHandler(ForwardingApplication.java:367) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.init(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:95) [omnifaces-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1-20140603]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:111) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:85)
```

The relevant configuration in `web.xml` is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: When do you end up with these exceptions? Do you mean, when OmniFaces is removed, you run the application with no problem at all?

Comment: This suggests that the filter's `init()` has failed. Have you checked server's startup logs for clues possibly related to that? How exactly have you configured FacesViews related context parameters in `web.xml`, if any?

Comment: @Tiny I cannot remove omnifaces as my application heavily use it. Those exceptions just show up in the log files and I am trying right now to determine when. I think it is related with the expired session, but I still was not able to reproduce it.

I extended my post by the content of web.xml and faces-config.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Those NPEs suggest that the filter's initialization failed. You should be able to find clues earlier in the log, during server's startup.

> 2015-02-11 12:28:35,667 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /terms/index: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set ViewHandler after a response has been rendered.

That `IllegalStateException` is a helpful hint. The `FacesViewsViewHandler` was in OmniFaces 1.x via the `FacesViewsForwardingFilter` lazily initialized on first request on an URL matching `/*.xhtml`. However, that would fail with exactly that exception if the `FacesServlet` is invoked *before* the filter. You have there a suspicious `*.html` mapping which would trigger `FacesServlet` without triggering the filter. Do you have a plain HTML page as welcome file or so? Why not renaming that to `*.xhtml`?

In any case, that initialization ordering bug was [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/0d8e788b70c8f2f06fe57ea271227bda40b435b3) in OmniFaces 2.0. So, upgrading should do.